# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face' despite using "opencv_extras" recipe

Tags: kivy, buildozer, opencv, python

I'm facing this error `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'` when testing on Android. I've got `opencv` and `opencv_extras` included in requirements. This error won't show up when running on desktop but it shows up when tested on Android.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate I also faced the same error today.....
Well the solution is uninstalling your current version of python and installing new version, that is downgrading your current version of opencv
`opencv-contrib-python==3.4.6.27`

Also this can be verified by typing
`help(cv2.face)` in the IDE
if it shows the path the version opencv would work...

Well the above version of opencv I mentioned does have cv2.face

So to install it you type
`pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.6.27` in the cmd or whatever depending upon your environment

Comment: The thing is when I ran `print(dir(cv2.face))` it printed out all the attributes incl. the ones I need but it's like Android can't used them. Are you suggesting that I need to downgrade opencv to 3 in order to make it work on Android ?

Comment: Apologies I dont about android but for python this is one the way...